# Add customer email address to new account email notification in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am trying to insert the customer email address in "new account" email.

So far I tried using `$user_email` instead of `$user_login` and `$order->billing_email` in a hook but it shows blank space every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** You can use a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_email_header` action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'add_customer_billing_email', 20, 2 );
function add_customer_billing_email( $email_heading, $email )
{
    // Only for  "Customer new account" email notifications
    if( $email->id != 'customer_new_account' ) return;

    // Get user billing email
    global $user_login;
    $user = get_user_by('login', $user_login );
    $email = $user->billing_email;

    // HTML Output
    echo '<p>'.__('Billing email').': <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a></p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

---

Or you can insert in the template `emails/customer-new-account.php` the following code, in the location of your choice:

```
<?php
    // Get user billing email
    $user = get_user_by('login', $user_login );
    $email = $user->billing_email;

    // HTML Output
    echo '<p>'.__('Billing email').': <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a></p>';
?>
```

Tested and works.

Official documentation: [Overriding WooCommerce templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: How can I apply this to customer-new-account.php file? In this email there are no order_table, details, meta?

Comment: Thanks! But the file template customer-new-account.php doesn't have woocommerce_email_order_details. See the code of the file here: https://codeshare.io/2EpXo8 Using WC 2.6.14

Comment: @Tsakov Yes sorry, you are completely right… I have updated my answer.

Comment: I had to use `$user = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
$email = $user->user_email;` to get new user email